# Unable to join two oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 tables.
First table SEC_SEAL_LOG with columns:

```
DATA_ADD,
DATA_AREA,
SEAL_NUMBER,
DATA_SEALING,
DATA_UNPLUG,
SORRUPTED.
SEC_WRITING_OFF_SEALS
```

second table with columns:

```
DATA, SEAL.
```

I want to put these 2 tables together, but I cannot understand where I have the error, I will be grateful for your help.

```
select DATA_ADD,
       DATA_AREA,
       SEAL_NUMBER,
       DATA_SEALING,
       DATA_UNPLUG,
       СORRUPTED,
       Data
from SEC_SEAL_LOG,SEC_WRITING_OFF_SEALS
where  (data_area = (select data_area 
                     from SEC_USERS_LIST 
                     where login = LOWER(:APP_USER) 
                     and SEAL_NUMBER = SEAL 
                    )
            or 20 >= (select u.role 
                      from SEC_users_list u 
                      where u.login = lower(:APP_USER)
                    )
        ) 
and СORRUPTED = 'Так'  
and SEAL_NUMBER = SEAL
ORDER BY  data_add DESC
```

I amd getting this error

> ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!
>
> ORA-06550: line 7, column 4: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: I use ORACLE  12

Comment: What is the error?? .

Comment: If you are getting an Error, ALWAYS show us what the error is, all the error message please not a summary of it

Comment: You really should be using JOIN rather that `from SEC_SEAL_LOG,SEC_WRITING_OFF_SEALS`

Comment: ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 7, column 4: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined</p>

Comment: *" column ambiguously defined"* That why you should always use fully qualified tables or use aliases in the SQL language in general... Or you write  `SELECT table_name.columns_name FROM table_name` ("fully" qualified as the database name also can be included which makes it `SELECT database_name.table_name.columns_name FROM table_name`) or use `SELECT alias_name.column_name FROM table_name AS alias_name` (aliased)

Comment: Somehow?select 
      SEC_SEAL_LOG.DATA_ADD,
      SEC_SEAL_LOG.DATA_AREA,
      SEC_SEAL_LOG.SEAL_NUMBER,
       SEC_WRITING_OFF_SEALS.Data
  from SEC_SEAL_LOG,SEC_WRITING_OFF_SEALS

Comment: something like that yes, but i would also follow @RiggsFolly suggestion about using `JOIN` instead of the old comma JOIN..  Topicstarter i assume you didn't notice your SQL is a Cartesian Product between SEC_SEAL_LOG and SEC_WRITING_OFF_SEALS  before that result is filterd ?  i am pretty sure that query could be (re)written better if you share the data and expected results... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: .. (but maybe you need to do it in a other question)  i could not add that annymore to that other comment as performance/complete SQL rewite is not related to the error in the question..

Comment: I have 2 tables, a table of seals, and a table of written seals, I want to list them by the number of seals. And output information DATA_ADD,
       DATA_AREA,
       SEAL_NUMBER,
       DATA_SEALING,
       DATA_UNPLUG,
       СORRUPTED,
       Data (write-off date)

Comment: Your example data and expected results should ideally be asked in a new question, maybe you also give a explainment and link to this question that you had a *"column ambiguously defined"* error to avoid the question to be marked as *"duplicated"*.. Be sure to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections *"Help others reproduce the problem/Proof-read before posting!"*

Comment: .. Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for help into providing a testable user case

Answer (score 1):

The error `Column Ambiguously Defined` occurs when a column name is present in more than one table, and you have failed to specify which table.

You are doing that in this line: `and SEAL_NUMBER = SEAL` (which you have twice).

From which table to you want to compare that SEAL value?

Write it as `SEC_SEAL_LOG.SEAL` or `SEC_WRITING_OFF_SEALS.SEAL` or whatever table name you are trying to compare this value from, and it will get rid of the `Column Ambiguously Defined` error.